# Change data attribute values based on differing data attribute values for each div with a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I have several divs where the `data-resort` and `data-resortavail` are manipulated via checkboxes and such. What I am trying to do is, whenever `data-resort` or `data-resortavail` changes, it updates `data-view`. What I have here obviously isn't working, and I am confused as to why. Any help is appreciated.

I received this comment:

> I don't understand why you're not updating data-view on the click
> event. "What I am trying to do is, whenever data-resort or
> data-resortavail changes, it updates data-view...". You're setting the
> values on click, so you know the values you're setting, you don't need
> a function to check them.

Hopefully, this creates more clarity.
The simple answer is, because the checkboxes do not control `data-resortavail`. However, `data-resortavail` is a portion of what controls `data-view`. I do not want to change `data-view` with the checkbox because then it will not give me what I need.

The checkbox only changes `data-resort`. An ajax search controls `data-resortavail`. Since the checkbox controls `data-resort` I need to update `data-view` pending the values of `data-resort` and `data-resortavail`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="AKV-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="AKV2-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="AULV-container" class="resortcontainer ntp" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="BLT-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="BCV-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="BWALK-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="VWL-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="WCC-container" class="resortcontainer" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="GCAL-container" class="resortcontainer" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>
```

**Working Checkboxes (lack`findAttributes();`)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    j$('.filterCheckBox').click(function() {
        if( j$(this).is(':checked')) {
            j$("."+this.value).attr('data-resort',1);
            j$("#"+this.value).attr('data-resort',1);
            attributeCount();
            findAttributes();
        } else {
            j$("."+this.value).attr('data-resort', 0);
            j$("#"+this.value).attr('data-resort', 0);
            attributeCount();
            findAttributes();
            }
        })
    })
```

**My attempt at changing `data-view` based on the other two attributes `data-resort` and `data-resortavail`**

```
let findAttributes = function(response){
   j$('.resortcontainer').each(function(){
     let countavail = j$(this).data("resortavail");
     let countfilter = j$(this).data("resort");
     if (countavail == 1 && countfilter == 1) {
        j$(this).attr('data-view',1);
     }
     else {
        j$(this).attr('data-view',0);
     }
   })
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're not updating data-view on the click event. "What I am trying to do is, whenever data-resort or data-resortavail changes, it updates data-view...". You're setting the values on click, so you know the values you're setting, you don't need a function to check them.

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: IMO this is the minimal relevant code. The question at hand is. Why is checking or unchecking a checkbox not updating my ```data-view``` value? The checkbox itself has nothing to do with ```data-resortavail``` and ```data-resortavail``` makes a difference in the ```data-view``` value.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue. Now everything works accordingly. I think the issue was my `findAttributes()`. I don't believe it was actually looping correctly. But, here is how I solved it.

**HTML** Note: There are a lot of "-container" ids on the site, so I opted to change the ids ending with -result-container. Just to make the query more accurate.

```
<div id="AKV-result-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="AKV2-result-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="AULV-result-container" class="resortcontainer ntp" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="BLT-result-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="BCV-result-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="BWALK-result-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="VWL-result-container" class="resortcontainer wdw" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="WCC-result-container" class="resortcontainer" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>

<div id="GCAL-result-container" class="resortcontainer" data-resort="1" data-resortavail="1" data-view="1"></div>
```

**Function that allows my checkboxes to change my first data attribute.**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    j$('.filterCheckBox').click(function() {
        if( j$(this).is(':checked')) {
            j$("."+this.value).attr('data-resort',1);
            j$("#"+this.value).attr('data-resort',1);
            findAttributes();
            attributeCount();
        } else {
            j$("."+this.value).attr('data-resort', 0);
            j$("#"+this.value).attr('data-resort', 0);
            findAttributes();
            attributeCount();
            }
        })
    })
```

**Function to compare two different Data Attributes.**

```
let findAttributes = function(response){
 var resultcontainers =  document.querySelectorAll('[id$="-result-container"]');
 resultcontainers.forEach(function(resultcontainer){
      if (resultcontainer.dataset.resort == 1 && resultcontainer.dataset.resortavail == 1) {
        j$(resultcontainer).attr("data-view",1);
      }
      else{
        j$(resultcontainer).attr("data-view",0);
      }
 })
}
```